# Static time analysis in Microsemi's Libero® SoC v11.8 SP3

Tags: vhdl, delay, clock, analysis, timing

How do I set the clock-to-out delay constraint in Microsemi's Libero® SoC v11.8 SP3 Constraint Editor Tool?

When I change the value for clock to `out delay constraint`:

```
Verify post layout simulation > Open SmartTime > Constraint Editor > Output Delay > Clock to out delay
```

There is no change in the required time calculation.

Comment: Is there a [programming questioning](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here? Perhaps this belongs on another site? There is no VHDL present in your question, your problem isn't visible nor are constraints a programming language.

Comment: No, it is not programming question but after writing a program only we expect a software to design its hardware and then we verify all the timing characteristics so my question is related to static timing analysis.